# Could not load type 'System.Web.Script.AjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web.Extensions,

Tags: asp.net-4.0, toolkitscriptmanager

I recently switched to VS 2010. While using `AjaxToolkit version=4.1.51116.0`, I am getting run-time error :

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Script.AjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute'
>   from assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.****

This error is coming while using any of the AJAX toolkit control.
I am using ToolkitScriptManager.

How to solve this error?
suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Using xsp4, I get the following error messages in console:
Missing method .ctor in assembly AjaxControlToolkit.dll, type System.Web.Script.AjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: AjaxControlToolkit.dll mtoken: 0x0a000032

Comment: [Mono System.Web.Extensions in 4.0 vs MS.NET 4.0](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Web.Extensions)  shows System.Web.Script and AjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute as "Missing: we need it". [asp.net form](http://forums.asp.net/t/1760395.aspx) suggests reverting to the version you're already using. I had no luck either